# What happens if a Dothraki Khal goes bald naturally?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Since Dothraki pride their voracity and skill in battle via their hair:

> Dothraki warriors wear their hair in a long braid and only cut it when defeated, so the world may see their shame.  Very capable warriors therefore often have a very long braid.
>
> -- [Dothraki Warrior](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Dothraki)

**If a Khal was to go bald, what would happen to his status as a Khal?**

---

Canon answer to this are preferred but even out-of-universe answers would be welcome.

Comment: How do you mean, "what would happen"? And what would an "out of universe answer" look like to a question like this - do you mean an answer about what happens if a Khal's actor goes bald in GoT?

Comment: That's just repeating the question. What do you mean, "what would happen"? What would happen to his pride? His appearance? His status? His hygiene? His followers? His love life? His fighting prowess? Simply asking "what would happen" seems rather broad and open-ended.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, His status as a Khal. Feel free to edit if the question feels vague to you

Comment: Probably most Dothraki Khals did not live long enough to become bald from aging...

Comment: @Loki There are examples of old Khals but there are no examples of naturally bald Khals IIRC. Could be that they just have good hair genes as a people since there's literally no Dothraki man/boy mentioned who doesn't have long hair or isn't growing it long. Weak argument though given their rape tendencies and pillaging life style.

Comment: It's pretty rare for anyone to go 100% bald. Even with aggressive pattern baldness, they'd end up with a horseshoe pattern (appropriately enough) and still be able to grow long hair on the back and sides.

Comment: 'only cut it when defeated' -->  but you can lose hair without cutting eg going bald...?

Comment: It's possible that with hair being such a status symbol in their society, balding men would be shunned by the group and unfavoured by women meaning centuries of genetic selection on this basis mean men are very unlikely to go bald. As another point on genetics, [various ethnic groups](http://www.hairlossexpert.co.uk/hair-loss-types-different-ethnic-groups.html) experience hair loss differently, and maybe the ancestors of the Dothraki just mean they are prone to good hair by default.

Comment: Would the culture accept a wig or a toupee or a merkin?

Comment: @Nemon27, a very good point!!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

NOTE: For a *word of god* answer, see Skooba's answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/204060/54887).

Begin my speculative answer.

---

There's no example of a naturally bald Khal in the canon so we cannot draw on precedence.

As far as the implications such a condition would have on his status as a Khal, I believe it wouldn't be much of a problem.

Dothraki follow strength, not hair. That's the only thing they look for when choosing a leader.

The hair's importance is merely that it indicates how many battles has that person won. But it is not the only indicator of a Khal's strength and victories. The number of cities he razes, his personal wealth, the number of horses in his herds, the size of the Khalasar surrounding him, they all indicate his strength and victories. As long as they are sufficiently impressive, I do not see why his hair would be a problem.

Comment: The Dothraki following strength is a good point, but wouldn't baldness be seen as a sign of weakness?

Comment: Well, as long as his single combat record still proves his strength..... feel free to challenge him if you think you can do better ?

Comment: Is there any chance that the 'mystic' people in their society (don't know the correct name for them, or if they have them) could say that the baldness is an omen or a sign of them going to fail or lose a battle, thereby making any balding Khal lose their power due to a [self fulfilling prophesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy)?

Comment: @Nemon27 No. This isn't a Samson situation where the hair is thought to provide power.  Instead, it's a form of bragging about successes.

Comment: @kuhl Yes, I know that their hair is only symbolic, what I'm suggesting with the self fulfilling prophesy idea is that by saying a balding Khal will fail (as a prophesy by one of the dosh khaleen perhaps, whether true or otherwise) will cause them to. Their physical strength won't deplete, but superstition could make people think they're losing their edge or take it as a sign of an imminent defeat, and since power is derived from your reputation they will fail as their khalasar loses faith in them taking the baldness as an incorrect sign of any real power loss.

Comment: @khul Imagine the following dialogue (but in Dothraki): 1 - "Have you noticed the khal is losing his hair?" 2 - "I thought so, I was riding beside him yesterday and thought it was thinner." 1 - "I heard one of the women say that balding men are weaker." 2 - "Hmm, I wonder if that really is the case." It only takes a few of these conversations before everyone thinks the khal is going weak because of his balding hair, and even though it's not true that fact people believe it *could* be true means they don't fight as hard or respect him as much and it snowballs into him literally losing power.

Comment: @Nemon27  Of course there's "a chance" the mystics would say that. And there's a chance the mystics would say because "The bald Khal has no hair, his hair can never be cut. He is incapable of being defeated!" Or something else - the mystics are probably very skilled at spinning things however they want.. I don't think putting words into the mouths of Dotrhaki mystics contributes much to the discussion.

Comment: @Gregor I like your spin, makes my argument a moot point, well played +1

Answer (score 6):

**They would likely be "dethroned", but may be able to stay in power if they can show sufficient strength.**

I reached out to [Elio Garcia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59933/elio-miguel-garcia-jr) and Linda Antonsson on Twitter (as they have been responsive and helpful to our community). As the co-authors of *[The World of Ice and Fire](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_World_of_Ice_%26_Fire)* they have a close relationship with George, and while what they say may not be 100% canon it can at least give a level of insight beyond guessing.

> **@SFFSkooba** What would happen to a Dothraki would went bald, especially a kahl? Would they been seen as unfit or weak, would they braid their beard in lieu of their hair? We have very little info on kahls who made it to an older age...
>
> **@westerosorg** Interesting question1 I suspect they would be considered unfit somehow, if they went totally bald. But presumably a good way with an arakh might convince naysayers otherwise.
>
> Source: [Twitter @westerosorg](https://twitter.com/westerosorg/status/1071684627482464257)